# What is the right word for converting slides into pictures?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

I'd like to know the correct word for converting PowerPoint presentation slides into a PowerPoint slideshow which consists of images of the original slides (so that the contents does not shift when presenting on a different computer).
Please help me to find the word describing  such a transformation.

Comment: I'm afraid that naming things is off topic for this site. Please read the [faq] for more information.

Comment: @Matt: Thank you for the link. May I then edit the question so that it does not mention the program but just asks for the correct word?

Comment: Yes, if you reword your question to ask for a word for a process, rather than a name for a product, that would probably be acceptable.

Comment: @utapyngo You can also try the [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Zairja: Thanks. Though I think the question now fits this site better than [ux](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), I would not object if the staff moves my question there.

Comment: Utapyngo, In PowerPoint, you can save a file as a "PowerPoint Show." When you do that, the presentation always opens in a Slide Show view on whatever computer it is launched on. The option is available under "Save As." It should keep all of your timings, if you used that. If that's not what you were asking about, I apologize.

Comment: @jlg But if someone copies the presentation to a computer with a different version of PowerPoint, it may or may not display correctly. I think that's the OP's original issue. But we're getting into computer issues and not English, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing, generally-accepted term, or are you proposing to invent a word? I don't know of any existing word. I generally save to PDF to solve this problem, and I refer to it as "saving to PDF" or "converting to PDF".

Comment: And are you looking for exporting to a file which can be run by PowerPoint on another system, just without permitting edits, or to a freestanding executable?

Comment: @Jay, yes, you are correct. The issue is that the contents may not display correctly. But I don't use PDF because it does not preserve slide transitions.
I am looking for a general word in the first place, but if I find nothing, I would have to use an invented word.
How do you think, would "pixelize" go? Or maybe "albumize"? (since the process involves converting the presentation into a "photo album", and then creating new slides from the album pictures)

Comment: I think that a word for converting a PP _slideshow_ into a non-PP _slideshow_ is OT/too localised to be of use to anybody else.

Comment: @coleopterist: Oh, I am not looking for a word for exactly PP, I am just trying to provide as much details as possible. A word for transforming *any* presentation into pictures will go.

I think you misunderstood the question. Both are PP presentations, but the first one contains text, and the second one contains nothing but pictures.

Comment: In that case, please reword your question to something like: "How would I describe the process where I _extract_ only the images from a slideshow?" or "How would I describe the process where I remove all non-picture elements from a slideshow?".

Comment: @coleopterist, I am not removing anything! I am converting slides to their pictures. So the picture looks the same as the slide with the only difference that it is a picture.

Comment: I see. I think @MετάEd's suggestion of _rasterise_ is a good one. Apologies for the noise.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood just what you are doing. RE "pixelize" See MetaEd's answer. "Rasterize" is a reasonably common term for converting line art to raster (pixel) images, so if that's what you're trying to say, there's no need to invent a new term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your question about a process of converting a slide deck to images made of pixels and creating a new slide deck from the converted images, it is correct to say that you are *rasterizing* or *ripping* the deck.

*[Rasterize](http://onelook.com/?w=rasterize)* and *[rip](http://onelook.com/?w=rip)* both mean “convert line art to a rasterized (pixelized) image”. That is, the image is recreated using pixels to approximate the original line art. A rasterized image is suitable for sending to a display device (such as a printer or monitor) or saving in a raster-format file (such as TIFF, PNG, or JPEG).

*Rasterize* means “[take] an image described in a vector graphics format (shapes) and [convert] it into a raster image ([rows of] pixels or dots) for output on a video display or printer, or for storage in a bitmap file format”. (*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterize)*)

The verb *rip* is related to *rasterize* but less well known. It is mainly used in the art and publishing world when the line art is in PostScript format. *Rip* derives from an acronym, *RIP*, short for “Raster Image Processor”, meaning a special-purpose system used for printing PostScript: a *RIP* converts PostScript to a raster image. The verb *rip* originally meant “to process PostScript to a raster image using a RIP”, but has come to be used more loosely for rasterization of other line art formats.

*Rasterize*’s parent word, *raster*, from the Latin *rastrum*, “rake”, ([*OEtmD*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=raster)), was originally a German electronics term meaning a series of rows “raked” out by a cathode ray tube’s electron beam. It is related to *rastrum*, a five-pointed pen resembling a rake and used to draw musical staff lines.

[image]
[image]

Comment: From a technical perspective, this is incorrect and would lead to more confusion, resulting in the same explanation given in the original question.

Comment: @horatio As someone who does graphic design professionally I stand by my answer and respectfully ask you to support your comment with references.

Comment: Thanks. Would not "rasterize" mean that the result is a raster file such as TIFF, PNG, or JPEG? Because the result is still a presentation in PPT/PPS format. I also thought that *rip* was used for sounds only.

Comment: I've been a graphic designer for more than 20 years. As you well know, a PPT file is only a PPT file on the disk, and is rasterized the moment it is rendered to the screen. The term is far too generic and frankly, unresponsive to the question as asked. Anyone who knows what rasterizing means will have to ask what the desired result is, and the OP is left to explain all over again.

Comment: @utapyngo I have added more information about the words. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would just say "converting the slides to images*. I don't think there's anything more specific to the process than "converting".

Comment: Converting to images is only the first stage of the process. The result of it is a set of images, not a single presentation or slidshow file.

Comment: I would probably say "convert into a series of still images" or "export to image files" or something. It's not elegant, but I don't think there's one specific word.

Answer (score 0):

Without the desired end result you cannot get a good answer.

A software package is implicit in "slide show" (and so is "I don't do PDF because I lose the transitions"). As it stands, `export to X` or `convert to X` are your best options, but you will need to decide on what X is.